# Derivation of autocovariances of squared shocks

Tags: time-series, variance, stochastic-processes

I have two shocks: $\varepsilon_{1t}$ has constant volatility $E[\varepsilon_{1t}^2]$ = $\sigma^2_1$ while $\varepsilon_{2t}$ has time varying volatility $E[\varepsilon_{2t}^2]$ = $\sigma^2_{2,t}$. I further assume that:

$E[\varepsilon_{it}|\varepsilon_{jt}]=0$ for $j \neq i$ and every t

$E[\varepsilon_{it}|\varepsilon_{ks}]=0$ fo every $k$ and $s \neq t$

I am struggling to derive these quantities:

$cov(\varepsilon_{1t}^2, \varepsilon_{1t-p}^2)$

$cov(\varepsilon_{1t}^2, \varepsilon_{1t-p} \varepsilon_{2t-p})$

$cov(\varepsilon_{1t}^2,\varepsilon_{2t-p}^2)$

$cov(\varepsilon_{2t}^2,\varepsilon_{1t-p}^2)$

$cov(\varepsilon_{1t}\varepsilon_{2t},\varepsilon_{1t-p}^2)$

$cov(\varepsilon_{1t}\varepsilon_{2t},  \varepsilon_{1t-p}\varepsilon_{2t-p} )$

From the paper I am following it seems that all these quantities are equal to 0. I don't understand why. For the first quantity I derived

$cov(\varepsilon_{1t}^2, \varepsilon_{1t-p}^2)= E[\varepsilon_{1t}^2\varepsilon_{1t-p}^2] - (\sigma^2_1)^2$ but it is not clear to me how to show that $E[\varepsilon_{1t}^2\varepsilon_{1t-p}^2] = (\sigma^2_1)^2 $ to obtain 0.

Similarly for the other quantities, why $E[\varepsilon_{1t}^2\varepsilon_{1t-p} \varepsilon_{2t-p}]$ would be equal to 0?

Comment: Hi: are you sure they are all supposed to be zero because I worked on the first one and didn't get zero. Do you have a paper reference ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes! This is the paper https://www.restud.com/paper/identifying-shocks-via-time-varying-volatility/ . The covariances are at the bottom of page 3090.

Comment: Hi: I was able to find an accessible paper ( the one you sent is the published version ) that I guess is a draft. On page 6 of that draft, right under equation 3, it's says that $cov(\epsilon_{2t}, \epsilon_{2(t-p)}) \ne 0$ for some $p$. I don't have time to read the whole paper right now but doesn't that show that it's not zero ? I'm not sure on what page of the draft you are referring to when you say 390. If you type the name of the paper in google, it should come up. I'll be out  today if you respond but should see your response tonight. I'm sorry that I can't be of more help right now.

Comment: Now I see that you're only talking about $\epsilon_{1t}$ so my point in  comment above is irrelevant. But here's what I did to show it's not zero but maybe I made a mistake:  The link here shows that $E(\epsilon_{1t}^4) = 3 \sigma_{1}^2 $.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917647/proving-ex4-3%CF%834. Therefore $cov((\epsilon_{1t}^2, \epsilon_{1,(t-p)}^2)) = 3 \sigma_{1}^4 - (\sigma_1^2)^2 = 2 \sigma_{1}^4$.